error in PyTorch dataloader with num_workers>0 in VSC under WSL
I want to utilize my GPU by adjusting the workers number, but I have a problem with the number of workers > 0.
test_loader = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=32, shuffle=False, num_workers=0) - no problem
test_loader = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=32, shuffle=False, num_workers=1) - RuntimeError: CUDA error: initialization error
Data set is MNIST. The size is 50% / 50% train/test
Its NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Ti, Torch 2.0.1 + CUDA 1.18
GPU memory 8191.50 MB
I work within Visual Studio Code in WSL
Here a reference a to similar case.
Error when using pytorch num_workers in colab. when num_workers > 0
Any suggestions?
Thank you!
>>>EDIT<<<<
Demo script
    import tensorflow as tf
    
    # Check GPU availability
    print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')))
    
    # Simple model to test GPU functionality
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu', input_shape=(784,)),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
    ])
    
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    
    # Dummy data
    import numpy as np
    X_train = np.random.random((1000, 784))
    Y_train = np.random.randint(10, size=(1000,))
    
    # Train model
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=1, workers=1, use_multiprocessing=True)

Output
File "/home/kalin_stoyanov/EntMax_TSNE/my_venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/optimizers/optimizer.py", line 1253, in _internal_apply_gradients

  File "/home/kalin_stoyanov/EntMax_TSNE/my_venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/optimizers/optimizer.py", line 1345, in _distributed_apply_gradients_fn

  File "/home/kalin_stoyanov/EntMax_TSNE/my_venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/optimizers/optimizer.py", line 1340, in apply_grad_to_update_var

DNN library initialization failed. Look at the errors above for more details.

**System info** 
---- CPU Information ----
Physical cores: 12
Logical cores: 24

---- Memory Information ----
Total RAM (GB): 15.442893981933594
Available RAM (GB): 12.711883544921875

---- GPU Information ----
PyTorch GPU Count: 1
PyTorch GPU 0: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Ti
PyTorch Version: 2.0.1+cu118
TensorFlow GPUs: ['/device:GPU:0']
TensorFlow Version: 2.14.0
Keras Version: 2.14.0

---- Operating System Information ----
Operating System: Linux
OS Version: #1 SMP Fri Mar 29 23:14:13 UTC 2024
Machine: x86_64

---- Python Information ----
Python Version: 3.11.4
Python Executable: /home/kalin_stoyanov/EntMax_TSNE/my_venv/bin/python
PyTorch Version: 2.0.1+cu118
TensorFlow Version: 2.14.0
Keras Version: 2.14.0
---- Num GPUs Available ----
Num GPUs Available (TensorFlow): 1


Can you make a small reproducible example of this?

added reproducible example

you posted a tensorflow sample code that has nothing to do with using a pytorch dataloader

I terribly sorry!

Consider this question as solved. I was really tired and mismatched PyTorch and Tensorflow codes. Sorry! The problem I have is with Tensorflow, not with PyTorch. If there is no solution here, I will create new question with reproducible code included.
